# Quais informações eu posso obter do usuário através do Java EE?

Tags: java, java-ee, active-directory

Preciso implementar SSO(Single Sign-On) em um cliente da empresa que trabalho, o cenário é basicamente o seguinte: Eles possuem um sistema web, feito em java, que tem um login normal, porém eles querem que não exista uma tela de login e que essa verficação seja feita contra um Active Directory que eles possuem. Por isso gostaria de saber quais informações posso usar a respeito do usuário. Ja me foi sugerido frameworks como Waffle, Kerberos e SPNEGO, mas achei que são demasiadamente complicados de implementar. Gostaria que fosse o mais simples possível essa integração.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Eles precisam passar o usuário e senha para ser validado, um exemplo pra te ajudar seria esse bloco de código que eu implementei:

```
public static boolean authenticateJndi(String username, String password) throws Exception{
        try{    
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.1.5:389");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "login");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "senha");
        DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(props);
        System.out.println("Autenticado");
        context.close();
        return true;
        } catch(NamingException e){
            throw new NamingException("Houve um problema na autenticação");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, me mostrou um caminho. Ainda me paira uma dúvida, como eu faria para pegar por exemplo o nome de usuário da rede e passar como argumento na linha. props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "login");

Comment: Varia, depende do contexto. Este usuário terá de ser expressado em algum momento.